# How can I conditionally deploy a ContainerDefinition inside a TaskDefinition with CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to deploy some resources into AWS. What I want to do is - based on a condition deploy(or not) a ContainerDefinition inside a TaskDefinition.

```
Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    Properties:
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ---Other unimportant properties---
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: someServiceName
          ---Unimportant---
        - Name: ServiceToDeployBasedOnCondition
          Condition: IsProduction (this is defined in Conditions)
          ---Unimportant---
```

This is what I tried and I get "Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#: extraneous key [Condition] is not permitted".

How can I bypass this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nice approach. Utilizing Conditions is surely the way to fulfil your requirement here. You are receiving a model validation error because Conditions have to be placed at the top level of your resource https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html

```
# Example obtained from the docs

Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0ff8a91507f77f867
  MountPoint:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment'
    Condition: CreateProdResources
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2Instance
      VolumeId: !Ref NewVolume
      Device: /dev/sdh
```

One "quick and dirty" way to solve your issue would be to have two Task Definitions (one triggering with Condition: IsProduction and one not). However, if you wanted to solve your problem in a more elegant way (use a single task definition), I would have a look at CloudFormation Condition Functions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if